# Compare two strings and return how much words are same using Asp.net

Tags: asp.net

How could I get after Comparing two strings and return how much words are same using Asp.net.

I have written some code here but it return only length of string:

```
string x = "Sabih Khan Afridi Sabih Khan Afridi";
string y = "Sabih Afridi";
int z = x.Length; int t = y.Length;
Label1.Text = "Total lengths: !st->" +z.ToString()+" <<>> 2nd-"+t;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] common = x.Split().Intersect(y.Split()).ToArray();
int count = common.Length;
```

plagiarism detection is not simple as above, you better use one of library for this, like [Anti-Plagiaris](http://sourceforge.net/projects/antiplagiarismc/) or [moss](http://theory.stanford.edu/~aiken/moss/). they are open source and you can check the implementation also

Comment: Dear Damith if you some more help me about comparison of two external files of ms word using asp.net and show how much words are same...you can say like plagiarism

Answer (score 0):

Use [Intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx) to get similar words.

```
IEnumerable<string> listX = x.Split(' ').Distinct();
IEnumerable<string> listY = y.Split(' ').Distinct();

var similarWords = listX.Intersect(listY);
int numberOfSimilarWords = similarWords.Count();
```

Update:
To Compare words from two files.
You just need to read those files

```
var firstFile = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\firstfile.txt", Encoding.ASCII).Split(' ').ToList();
var secondFile =File.ReadAllText(@"C:\secondfile.txt", Encoding.ASCII).Split(' ').ToList();

var similarwords=firstFile.Intersect(secondFile);
```

Comment: Dear Sachin if you some more help me about comparison of two external files of ms word using asp.net and show how much words are same...you can say like plagiarism

Comment: @BiLalKakakhel I have update the answer for reading from text file. Have a look and let me know if any issue

Comment: i have tried your code of text files but it shows error like System.Linq.Enumerable+d__92`1[System.String]

Comment: @BiLalKakakhel reading files in a ASP.NET application has it's own rules first you should upload the file to server or if you want to do this in client machine you should use JavaScript